# WCF uploading file not completed

Tags: c#, wcf, pdf

I'm trying to upload pdf/file with WCF.

My problem is , the file that I have uploaded isn't completed

someone can help me

this my function Upload :

```
public string UploadFile(FileUploadMessage request)
{
    Stream fileStream = null;
    Stream outputStream = null;
    try
    {
        fileStream = request.FileByteStream;

        string rootPath = @"C:\WCF";

        DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(rootPath);

        if (!dirInfo.Exists)
        {
            dirInfo.Create();
        }
        string newFileName = Path.Combine(rootPath, Guid.NewGuid() + ".pdf");
        outputStream = new FileInfo(newFileName).OpenWrite();
        const int bufferSize = 1024;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        int bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

        while (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }
        return newFileName;
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        throw new FaultException<IOException>(ex, new FaultReason(ex.Message));
    }
    finally
    {
        if (fileStream != null)
        {
            fileStream.Close();
        }
        if (outputStream != null)
        {
            outputStream.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

this is my configuration

```
<binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ITransferService" closeTimeout="04:01:00"
                     openTimeout="04:01:00" receiveTimeout="04:10:00" sendTimeout="04:01:00"
                     allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
                     hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                     maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                     maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                     messageEncoding="Mtom" textEncoding="utf-8"
                     transferMode="Streamed"
                     useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="128"
                        maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                        maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None"
                                proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
```

Comment: I don't see any code related to WCF.

Comment: It might be related to the file size. Check the quotas set in your WCF configuration file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to stream a byte[] (for example a file) to a WCF operation then the operation needs to have only one parameter of type Stream. The problem is that you then will need to know the length of the byte[] on the recieving end (the service).

One solution is to make two calls to two separate service operations

```
public void SetLength(long length)

public void Upload(Stream stream)
```

Where you save the length from the first call to be used in the second call.

With this solution you don't have to care about setting MaxRecievedMessageSize in config to some great number.

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this( Check this example http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/2008/upload-a-file-using-aspnet-file-upload-control-and-wcf):

```
class FileUploadService : IFileUploadService
```

{
    public bool UploadFileData(FileData fileData)
    {
        bool result = false;
        try
        {
            //Set the location where you want to save your file
            string FilePath = Path.Combine({YOUR path from some setting}, fileData.FileName);

```
        //If fileposition sent as 0 then create an empty file
        if (fileData.FilePosition == 0)
        {
            File.Create(FilePath).Close();
        }

        //Open the created file to write the buffer data starting at the given file position
        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.Read))
        {
            fileStream.Seek(fileData.FilePosition, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            fileStream.Write(fileData.BufferData, 0, fileData.BufferData.Length);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {            
        //throw FaultException<>();
    }

    return result;
}
```

}